# Change Apple Watch Water Lock

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

After the previous update on my Watch, the water lock feature now requires me to long press the crown. I find the earlier method of opening the water lock (by rotating the crown) more convenient.

Is there a way I can change the way the water lock opens on my Watch to the earlier method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately, you cannot change it to rotating the crown. This is a WatchOS level change that doesn't give users the option to change it.

Your only option is to downgrade to WatchOS 8.x, which isn't straightforward.